# space between Crystal Reports Cross-Tab Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I have crosstab crystal report in asp.net C# when it display there is unwanted white space between column in some interval. how can I remove the space please help me

Thank you, and please see report picture below

[image]

Comment: It's not unwanted space it is the space because there is no data for that interval..what you can do is to set 0 when there is no data

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me. 
**Remove (Keep Columns Together) check box option from cross tab expert.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either this report is large enough that all columns can not be printed on one page horizontally or the paper size selected for the report is too small. **These unwanted white spaces are the page margins**. If you print this report, columns upto 14... will print on the first page, 15... to 24... on the second page and 25... to 27... on the third page.

These white spaces can not be removed completely. But can be minimized only by reducing the page's left and right margins and adjusting the column widths. However the last column to be printed on each page will decide this white space. If the last column could not be printed on that page, it will automatically be moved to the next page leaving behind this white space.

The only alternative is use the largest paper size available (or custom paper size) with an orientation fit for the report. This alternative is viable only and only if you have the provision to print that large paper size or **if you do not want to print the report** and only view it on any digital device. But in that case too if the these dynamic columns again surpass the set paper size, there will again be a visible gap as those extra columns will again shift to a new page.

Comment: I have two cross tabs, and the wider does not have the gap.  I've made the one with a gap narrower, and it's displaying smaller, but still has the gap.  The end is well to the right of the header, which will fit on the page if printed.