# Crystal Reports Cross-tab space between columns in CR Viewer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer, crystal-reports-2013

I have a similar problem to this question: [space between Crystal Reports Cross-Tab Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305836/space-between-crystal-reports-cross-tab-column), but I'm pretty sure the gap is not caused by the page size.

In Crystal Reports (CR 2013), the cross tab displays just fine:

[image]

However, when I use the Crystal Viewer (SAP CR Viewer 2011), which my customers will have, there is a gap:

[image]

The page size should be fine, as the header fits fine.  In addition, I have a different cross tab on the first page, it is wider, and it doesn't have the gap.  The page size is set to landscape legal, no printer.

What other issues could be causing this?

Comment: If you look at the Cross-tab expert, is the checkbox "keep Columns together" checked? I have never seen this issue before. Maybe try removing any vertical guidelines?

Comment: @Aron - Yes, the "Keep Columns Together" is checked, both on the cross tab that works and the one with the break.  I think the vertical guidelines are all wanted, but until you said that, I didn't know I had control there. That's cool - thanks!

Comment: Interesting. You can remove the guidelines by right clicking on the report and selecting "remove all (vertical/Horizontal) guidelines" - worth a shot. Does any of this apply?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305836/space-between-crystal-reports-cross-tab-column